# Rails cocoon dynamic creation of link_to_add_association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I have a form which allows the adding of possibly hundreds of different association types to a form. I'm using the cocoon gem's `link_to_add_association` but rendering 100's of links is very slow as they're populated with all the html required to add them. Is there any way to dynamically create the links from an ajax request? The problem is `link_to_add_association` requires the form builder object which is unavailable after the initial page request.

As a side note the links are grouped so if I'm hoping to render the links for that particular group when it's clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rendering a new form for each request which seemed to work just fine.

Comment: If you feel like it close out the cocoon gem ticket too.

Comment: Still a bit unclear to me how you actually solved it? Instead of using `link_to_add_association` you just use links to the forms?

Comment: @nathanvda i ended up rendering an entirely new form containing just the desired link. originally i thought that would cause issues but it worked just fine. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this creating a form builder for the same object, and pass the object to the partial

**action.js.erb**

```
'<%= form_for(@object) do |ff| %>'
   $('#some_div').html("<%= j render(partial: 'some_partial', locals: {f: ff})%>"
'<% end %>'
```

note the single quotes, it's for avoing javascript_escape issues